# spring data elasticsearch nested object lookup

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

I'm new to Elasticsearch and I've been looking for a way to do a sort of recursive lookup for an object. I've got an object that looks like so:

```
@Document(indexName = "locations", shards = 1, replicas = 0)
@Setting(settingPath = "analyzer.json")
public class EsLocation {

    @Id
    private String id;
    
    @Field(type = FieldType.Text, analyzer = "index", searchAnalyzer = "search", fielddata = true)
    private String name;

    @Field(type = FieldType.Text, analyzer = "index", searchAnalyzer = "search", fielddata = true)
    private String displayName;

    @Field(type = FieldType.Keyword)
    private String type;

    @Transient
    private EsLocation parent;

    @Field(type = FieldType.Keyword)
    private String parentId;
}
```

So the EsLocation object contains itself in order to create a hierarchy. For example: Austin who's parent object is Texas who's parent object is USA whos parent object is North America. Another one would be Austin -> Quebec -> Canada -> North America. The number of parents might not always be 3, it varies depending on what user is looking for. The ID of the parent is always saved with the object so I know the exact city that is being referenced so there's no ambiguity, and it's null if it's top level location (continent). This works fine for mongodb where I can always look it up, but I've no idea how to move it to ES.

How should I go about doing this?

Comment: what is your actual problem? If you retrieve an entity you can check it's `parentId` and fetch the parent entity.

Comment: @P.J.Meisch Is that an OK solution? I was under impression that constantly hitting the DB drastically reduces the performance so it should be avoided. I could use `ElasticsearchOperations` with a for loop to query and set parent recursively as long as it's required, but I'm afraid what that would do the performance. I was hoping that ES could just automatically populate `parent` property if `parentId` was present and acting as a sort of foreign key. This is meant to be an autosuggest that would display results ala google maps, so searching for Austin you'd get Austin TX, USA or Austin, Canada

Comment: Elasticsearch does not provide such a referenced lookup. One thing you could do is add a readonly property which when its getter is called calculates the String to be searched for by gettting up the hierachy and canocatenating the names. This would then be stored in Elasticsearch and could be searched. But when retrieving, the parent objects will not be set. Or you might model this with a join type (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/parent-join.html and https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/4.2.5/reference/html/#elasticsearch.jointype)

Comment: I figured I'd do it with join types as a learning experience for ES, but I'm running out of time so I'll just implement it as a separate property. If you wanna post the above as a reply so I can mark it as a solution, cheers!